# Can I get the list of the packages whose configuration is needed to be purged?

Tags: dpkg

I Tried to get the list of all the removed packages whose configurations are to be purged through this command dpkg -l but there was a very huge list. Is there any command to get the list of all the packages which are needed to be purged?

Comment: command `dpkg -l` will list all packages so its a read only command ... notice at the top a header which explains meaning of the far left column of each package row

Answer (score 5):

You will be missing the header row, but the command

`dpkg-query -l | awk  '/^.c/'`

will list the packages in which only config files exist

---

The list of packages found by awk could be deleted with a change to the program

```
dpkg-query -l | awk  '/^.c/ { system("sudo dpkg --purge " $2) }'
```

It should be noted that I don't think this is a great idea:  I think it would be preferable to list the output from the search to a file, verify that you are ok with removing the packages named, and then use the text file as an input to dpkg:

```
dpkg-query -l | awk  '/^.c/' > ~/DpgkTargets
sudo nano ~/DpkgTargets
sudo dpkg --purge < ~/DpkgTargets
```

Comment: ok got it. How can I remove all those packages with a single command ?

Comment: @VivekSundaray  The 'system' command in awk could do it:  `dpkg-query -l | awk  '/^.c/ { system("sudo dpkg --purge " $2) }'` - it should go without saying that this should be used very cautiously.  I will expound in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not going to remove it but just wanted to know